# Regex to split a string based on \r characters not a carriage return or a new line

Tags: java, regex, string, apache-stringutils

i want a Regex expression to split a string based on `\r` characters not a carriage return or a new line.

Below is the sample string i have.

```
MSH|^~\&|1100|CB|CERASP|TESTSB8F|202008041554||ORU|1361|P|2.2\rPID|1|833944|21796920320|8276975
```

i want this to be split into

```
MSH|^~\&|1100|CB|CERASP|TESTSB8F|202008041554||ORU|1361|P|2.2
PID|1|833944|21796920320|8276975
```

currently i have something like this

```
StringUtils.split(testStr, "\\r");
```

but it is splitting into

```
MSH|^~
&|1100|CB|CERASP|TESTSB8F|202008041554||ORU|1361|P|2.2
PID|1|833944|21796920320|8276975
```

Comment: If my answer did not solve your problem please consider updating the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `String#split`:

```java
final String str = "MSH|^~\\&|1100|CB|CERASP|TESTSB8F|202008041554||ORU|1361|P|2.2\\rPID|1|833944|21796920320|8276975";
        
final String[] substrs = str.split("\\\\r");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(substrs));
// Outputs [MSH|^~\&|1100|CB|CERASP|TESTSB8F|202008041554||ORU|1361|P|2.2, PID|1|833944|21796920320|8276975]
```

Comment: no it doesnt work it thinks \r is a carriage return but  not string "\r"

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```java
import java.utl.regex.*;
//...
String[] results = text.split(Pattern.quote("\\r"));
```

The `Pattern.quote` allows using any plain text inside `String.split` that accepts a valid regular expression. Here, `\` is a special char, and needs to be escaped for both Java string interpretation engine and the regex engine.

Answer (score 0):

The method being called matches any one of the contents in the delimiter string as a delimiter, not the entire sequence.  Here is the code from SeparatorUtils that executes the delimiter (str is the input string being split) check:

```
if (separatorChars.indexOf(str.charAt(i)) >= 0) {
```

As @enzo mentioned, `java.lang.String.split()` will do the job - just make sure to quote the separator.  `Pattern.quote()` can help.